# ASP.Net triggering events as text is typed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, events

I am trying to make a voucher form where users will need to have to type the amount and have it translated right away

My issue would be that if they type the amount as number, the other textbox would only get populated if the user checks a checkbox with AutoPostBack set as true

Another field would be selection of bank account and having the IBAN appear right away

I have read somewhere that this could only be accomplished by using Java/JavaScript but I have no idea where I read that as it was a long time ago

I need to trigger an event/function instantly as the user types/selects from drop down list

Comment: Are you using webforms or mvc?
If I were to do this, i would most likely use angularJs, for it.

Comment: I am using webforms. Would you recommend mvc for this job and what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Iam not sure if there is 2 way binding in webforms without the postback. So i would recommend using AngularJs as here: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp. The difference between webforms and mvc is only a google search away: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/668182/Difference-betweeen-ASP-NET-WebForms-and-ASP-NET-M